# python skpy search user not working

Tags: python-2.7, skype

i want to search username with skpy, my actual code is :

```
from skpy import Skype, SkypeContacts
import skpy

sk = Skype("username", "password") # connect to Skype


print sk.search('test')
```

error:

AttributeError: 'Skype' object has no attribute 'SkypeContacts'

how i can search user with this library ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this,

```
from skpy import Skype, SkypeContacts

sk = Skype("username", "password")
sr = SkypeContacts(sk).search("test")
print (sr)
```